# Is it possible to see the source of a comment?

Tags: feature-request, comment

Like the title says, it seems useful to be able to "edit" a comment (just for the sake of seeing the tex). Does this feature exist ?

Comment: See [How to copy mixture of text and latex formulas in a comment?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/how-to-copy-mixture-of-text-and-latex-formulas-in-a-comment) And, of course, to view TeX source of a single formula (not the whole comment) you can use right click and select Show Math As/TeX Commands from the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I do it. I view the page using a text-based browser, e.g. [lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29), [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_%28web_browser%29), or [emacs-w3m](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3m). TeX doesn't get rendered under these browsers.

Comment: Without recurring to another browser, using the "show source page" feature of the browser you can see latex code of the comments. Sure it is more difficult to find the required place in the html code.